# Java styling JList for a chat

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am trying to figure out how to add the styling a functionality to a JList to make it function (close button if item is select) (new message icon if new message if received) like its done here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [livechatinc.com](http://cdn.livechatinc.com/website/media/img/devices/windows/main-feature_v3.png))</sub>

Im thinking of the list with "Anna, Lucy and Joe"

Any ideas how that could be achieved?

Edit: switched to the correct picture :)

Comment: Where is the 'close button'?

Comment: JList is container for non_editable JComponents, then you wound need to play with mouse events over Icon and to determine an item from JList, all those things can complicating wrong XxxRenderer

Comment: A two-column `JTable` might be easier for the close button.

Comment: I don't think that JTable is a good base for this specific component, at least if you want to style it properly without extra pain :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do what you asked for. I can't really say which way is better - using `JList`, creating your own component, painting the whole component from a scratch or something else.

Each approach has its own pros and cons:

- `JList` is faster in rendering and somewhat cleaner in the code
- Custom component is easier to write, style and listen for various events
- Painting component from a scratch is hard but might give a better rendering speed and usability

I don't really think that `JTable` will help you here anyhow better than `JList` - it has the same rendering strategy. Yes, it has editors, but using them like buttons or such seems a bit odd to me.

After playing about 15-20 minutes with `JList` renderer i made a full copy of the list from your screenshot (except icons - i just picked my own ones). Here is the screenshot of the example listed below:

[image]

`JList` is actually a pretty powerful tool if you know how to use it.

Here is the source code for that example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

/**
 * @author Mikle Garin
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18589264/909085
 */

public class CustomListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
    private static final ImageIcon crossIcon = new ImageIcon ( CustomListRenderer.class.getResource ( "cross.png" ) );
    private static final ImageIcon tipIcon = new ImageIcon ( CustomListRenderer.class.getResource ( "tip.png" ) );

    /**
     * Sample frame with list.
     *
     * @param args arguments
     */
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Custom list renderer" );

        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel ();
        model.addElement ( new CustomData ( new Color ( 209, 52, 23 ), 1, "Anna Williams" ) );
        model.addElement ( new CustomData ( new Color ( 135, 163, 14 ), 0, "Lucy Frank" ) );
        model.addElement ( new CustomData ( new Color ( 204, 204, 204 ), 0, "Joe Fritz" ) );
        model.addElement ( new CustomData ( new Color ( 90, 90, 90 ), 3, "Mikle Garin" ) );

        JList list = new JList ( model );
        list.setCellRenderer ( new CustomListRenderer ( list ) );
        list.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 5, 5, 5, 5 ) );
        frame.add ( list );

        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    /**
     * Actual renderer.
     */
    private CustomLabel renderer;

    /**
     * Custom renderer constructor.
     * We will use it to create actual renderer component instance.
     * We will also add a custom mouse listener to process close button.
     *
     * @param list our JList instance
     */
    public CustomListRenderer ( final JList list )
    {
        super ();
        renderer = new CustomLabel ();

        list.addMouseListener ( new MouseAdapter ()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased ( MouseEvent e )
            {
                if ( SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton ( e ) )
                {
                    int index = list.locationToIndex ( e.getPoint () );
                    if ( index != -1 && list.isSelectedIndex ( index ) )
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = list.getCellBounds ( index, index );
                        Point pointWithinCell = new Point ( e.getX () - rect.x, e.getY () - rect.y );
                        Rectangle crossRect = new Rectangle ( rect.width - 9 - 5 - crossIcon.getIconWidth () / 2,
                                rect.height / 2 - crossIcon.getIconHeight () / 2, crossIcon.getIconWidth (), crossIcon.getIconHeight () );
                        if ( crossRect.contains ( pointWithinCell ) )
                        {
                            DefaultListModel model = ( DefaultListModel ) list.getModel ();
                            model.remove ( index );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    /**
     * Returns custom renderer for each cell of the list.
     *
     * @param list         list to process
     * @param value        cell value (CustomData object in our case)
     * @param index        cell index
     * @param isSelected   whether cell is selected or not
     * @param cellHasFocus whether cell has focus or not
     * @return custom renderer for each cell of the list
     */
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent ( JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus )
    {
        renderer.setSelected ( isSelected );
        renderer.setData ( ( CustomData ) value );
        return renderer;
    }

    /**
     * Label that has some custom decorations.
     */
    private static class CustomLabel extends JLabel
    {
        private static final Color selectionColor = new Color ( 82, 158, 202 );

        private boolean selected;
        private CustomData data;

        public CustomLabel ()
        {
            super ();
            setOpaque ( false );
            setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 0, 36 + 5, 0, 40 ) );
        }

        private void setSelected ( boolean selected )
        {
            this.selected = selected;
            setForeground ( selected ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK );
        }

        private void setData ( CustomData data )
        {
            this.data = data;
            setText ( data.getName () );
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

            if ( selected )
            {
                Area area = new Area ( new Ellipse2D.Double ( 0, 0, 36, 36 ) );
                area.add ( new Area ( new RoundRectangle2D.Double ( 18, 3, getWidth () - 18, 29, 6, 6 ) ) );
                g2d.setPaint ( selectionColor );
                g2d.fill ( area );

                g2d.setPaint ( Color.WHITE );
                g2d.fill ( new Ellipse2D.Double ( 2, 2, 32, 32 ) );
            }

            g2d.setPaint ( data.getCircleColor () );
            g2d.fill ( new Ellipse2D.Double ( 5, 5, 26, 26 ) );
            g2d.drawImage ( tipIcon.getImage (), 5 + 13 - tipIcon.getIconWidth () / 2, 5 + 13 - tipIcon.getIconHeight () / 2, null );

            if ( selected )
            {
                g2d.drawImage ( crossIcon.getImage (), getWidth () - 9 - 5 - crossIcon.getIconWidth () / 2,
                        getHeight () / 2 - crossIcon.getIconHeight () / 2, null );
            }
            else if ( data.getNewMessages () > 0 )
            {
                g2d.setPaint ( selectionColor );
                g2d.fill ( new Ellipse2D.Double ( getWidth () - 18 - 5, getHeight () / 2 - 9, 18, 18 ) );

                final String text = "" + data.getNewMessages ();
                final Font oldFont = g2d.getFont ();
                g2d.setFont ( oldFont.deriveFont ( oldFont.getSize () - 1f ) );
                final FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics ();
                g2d.setPaint ( Color.WHITE );
                g2d.drawString ( text, getWidth () - 9 - 5 - fm.stringWidth ( text ) / 2,
                        getHeight () / 2 + ( fm.getAscent () - fm.getLeading () - fm.getDescent () ) / 2 );
                g2d.setFont ( oldFont );
            }

            super.paintComponent ( g );
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
        {
            final Dimension ps = super.getPreferredSize ();
            ps.height = 36;
            return ps;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom data for our list.
     */
    private static class CustomData
    {
        private Color circleColor;
        private int newMessages;
        private String name;

        public CustomData ( Color circleColor, int newMessages, String name )
        {
            super ();
            this.circleColor = circleColor;
            this.newMessages = newMessages;
            this.name = name;
        }

        private Color getCircleColor ()
        {
            return circleColor;
        }

        private int getNewMessages ()
        {
            return newMessages;
        }

        private String getName ()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, this example requires some advanced knowledge of `Graphics2D`, otherwise you won't be able to fully mimic the source example. But that is just what you will have to know anyway if you want to create some really good UIs in the end.

Anyway, the only problem with `JList` with this case is that components which are used to render cells are not "active" meaning that you can put some button into renderer, but it won't act as a button - it will be a simple image of that button in the end. And of course you will not receive any events from such button.

One more thing that you can see like 10 buttons in the list (for example if you have 10 cells in the list) but only one real button with different settings will be used to render all those cells - that is the main optimization of `JList` - it doesn't create tons of components for each cell, it reuses single renderer for each single cell.

So you have to add your own mouse listener into the list and work with coordinates of mouse events on the list (that is actually not that hard). I did that in the example i posted above - small mouse listener to catch clicks on the cross "button".

Be aware that list has its own mouse listeners that select cells - you have to "collaborate" with those listeners to avoid any misbehavior in your own list.

P.S. I almost forgot, here are two icons i have used: <[image]> <[image]>
2nd one is white (cross icon), so i have highlighted it with braces - don't miss it! :)