# How to create a search bar with multiple filters?

Tags: java, swing

I am looking to create a search bar with several filters in java swing.

I would like to arrive at the result below.

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/08/2/1550565354-cj3db.png)

Unfortunately I tried to edit a jcombobox with autocomplete but I can not do anything.

Has anyone ever made such a development or will they be able to give me a lead to move forward?

thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681977/jcombobox-autocomplete?

Comment: When is the dropdown is supposed to be shown? When the user types first character? Easiest may be to create a popup menu and display it when the user enters a value in the text field.

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra Yes, the dropdown is supposed to be shown when the user types first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not one my best works. Maybe you can take this as a starting point?

```
public class JTextFieldWithMenu extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField entry;
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JPopupMenu popup;

    public JTextFieldWithMenu() {
        initComponents();

        entry.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

    }

    private void initComponents() {
        entry = new JTextField(40);
        entry.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                entry.setSelectionStart(0);
                entry.setSelectionEnd(0);
                entry.setCaretPosition(entry.getText().length());
            }
        });
        jLabel1 = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("TextFieldDemo");

        jLabel1.setText("Enter text to search:");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(jLabel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(entry, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        showPopup();
    }

    protected void showPopup() {
        if (popup != null)
            popup.setVisible(false);
        popup = null;
        if (entry.getText().length() == 0)
            return;
        popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        if (entry.getText().length() == 0) {
            popup.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            popup.removeAll();
            popup.add(new JMenuItem("Search for '" + entry.getText() + "' in Filter1"));
            popup.add(new JMenuItem("Search for '" + entry.getText() + "' in Filter2"));
            popup.add(new JMenuItem("Search for '" + entry.getText() + "' in Filter3"));
            if (!popup.isShowing())
                popup.show(entry, 0, entry.getHeight());
            else
                popup.revalidate();
            entry.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        showPopup();
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        showPopup();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JTextFieldWithMenu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sqay.png

JTable_Search.java

```
package JAVA_VIDEOS_TUTORIALS;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;



public class JTable_Search extends javax.swing.JFrame implements DocumentListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("fr.pasteque.pos.caching.LocalDB");
    private static Connection conn = null;
    public ArrayList<CustomData> ListArray = new ArrayList<CustomData>();

    /**
     * Creates new form JTable_Search
     */
    public JTable_Search() {
        initComponents();

        jText_Search.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

        // call findUsers function
        findUsers();

    }


    // function to connect to mysql database
    private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
                String url = "jdbc:h2:???";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // Should never happen
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
                        "Unable to run local cache database", e);
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }

 // function to return users arraylist with particular data 
    public ArrayList<User> ListUsers(String ValToSearch)
    {
        ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();

        String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id like '%%'";
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;

        try{

            if (ValToSearch.length()!=0) {

                String[] items = ValToSearch.split(";");
                List<String> ValToSearchByCol = Arrays.asList(items);

                for( int i  = 0; i < ValToSearchByCol.size(); i++)
                    {

                        if (ValToSearchByCol.get(i).indexOf("firstname") ==  0) { 

                            String searchFirstname = ValToSearchByCol.get(i).replace("firstname:", "");
                            System.out.println(searchFirstname);  
                            searchQuery += "AND LOWER(firstname) like LOWER('"+searchFirstname+"%')";
                        }
                        else if (ValToSearchByCol.get(i).indexOf("lastname") == 0) {

                            String searchLastname = ValToSearchByCol.get(i).replace("lastname:", "");
                            System.out.println(searchLastname);  
                            searchQuery += "AND LOWER(lastname) like LOWER('"+searchLastname+"%')";
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println(ValToSearchByCol.get(i));
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Veuillez saisir une valeur dans le champ recherche.", "Erreur", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }
                    }
            }

            Connection con = getConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(searchQuery);

            User user;

            while(rs.next())
            {
                user = new User(
                                 rs.getString("id"),
                                 rs.getString("firstname"),
                                 rs.getString("lastname"),
                                 rs.getString("name")
                                );
                usersList.add(user);
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return usersList;
    }

    // function to display data in jtable
    public void findUsers()
    {
        ArrayList<User> users = ListUsers(jText_Search.getText());
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID","Firstname","Lastname","Name"});
        Object[] row = new Object[4];

        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
        {
            row[0] = users.get(i).getId();
            row[1] = users.get(i).getFirstname();
            row[2] = users.get(i).getLastname();
            row[3] = users.get(i).getName();
            model.addRow(row);
        }
       jTable_Users.setModel(model);

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton_Search = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jText_Search = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable_Users = new javax.swing.JTable();
        JList_Search = new javax.swing.JList<CustomData>();

        jText_Search.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                jText_Search.setSelectionStart(0);
                jText_Search.setSelectionEnd(0);
                jText_Search.setCaretPosition(jText_Search.getText().length());
            }
        });

        jPopupMenu_Search = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        addPopup(jText_Search, jPopupMenu_Search);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton_Search.setText("Search");
        jButton_Search.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton_SearchActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jText_Search.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        jTable_Users.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTable_Users.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable_Users);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(27)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(JList_Search, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 416, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jText_Search)
                                .addGap(103)
                                .addComponent(jButton_Search))
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 584, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton_Search)
                        .addComponent(jText_Search, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(47)
                    .addComponent(JList_Search, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 105, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(45)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(75))
        );


        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 641, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 717, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>  

    ////DEBUT #1
    /** PG: Fonction qui crée un PopupMenu en dessous du JTextField avec comme MenuItems 
     * toutes les informations recherchables sur l'utilisateur + le text saisie dans le JTextField
     */
    protected void showPopup() {
        if (jPopupMenu_Search != null)
            jPopupMenu_Search.setVisible(false);
        jPopupMenu_Search = null;
        if (jText_Search.getText().length() == 0)
            return;
        jPopupMenu_Search = new JPopupMenu();
        jPopupMenu_Search.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        if (jText_Search.getText().length() == 0) {
            jPopupMenu_Search.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            jPopupMenu_Search.removeAll();

            //DEBUT #2
            /** PG: Rempli le PopupMenu avec comme MenuItems toutes les informations recherchables sur l'utilisateur,
             * en se basant sur la classe Search_User qui contient toutes les informations recherchables sur un utilisateur
             * et en concaténant dans les MenueItems ces informations + le texte saisi dans le JTextField
             */
            Search_User seacrch_user = new Search_User(jText_Search.getText());
            for (int i = 0; i < seacrch_user.getInfoUser().size(); i++) {
                JMenuItem item=new JMenuItem(seacrch_user.getInfoUser().get(i) + seacrch_user.getSerachValue());

                //DEBUT #3
                /** PG: Action lorsqu'on clique sur un MenuItems, on copie la valeur du MenuItems dans le 
                 * JList et on vide le JTextField
                 */
                item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ListArray.add(new CustomData(item.getText()));
                    DefaultListModel<CustomData> model = new DefaultListModel<CustomData> ();
                    for (int y=0; y<ListArray.size();y++) {
                        model.addElement(ListArray.get(y));

                    }
                    JList_Search.setModel(model);
                    JList_Search.setCellRenderer(new CustomListRenderer(JList_Search,ListArray));
                    JList_Search.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                    JList_Search.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                    JList_Search.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
                    JList_Search.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
                    jText_Search.setText("");
                  }

                //FIN #3

              });
                jPopupMenu_Search.add(item);
            }
            //FIN #2
            if (!jPopupMenu_Search.isShowing())
                jPopupMenu_Search.show(jText_Search, 0, jText_Search.getHeight());
            else
                jPopupMenu_Search.revalidate();
            jText_Search.requestFocus();
        }
    }
  //FIN #1

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        showPopup();
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        showPopup();
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        showPopup();
    }


    // Button Filter/search 
    private void jButton_SearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

        if (jText_Search.getText().length()==0) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Veuillez saisir une valeur dans le champ recherche.", "Attention", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {

            findUsers();
        }

    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JTable_Search().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Search;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable_Users;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jText_Search;
    private javax.swing.JList<CustomData> JList_Search;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu jPopupMenu_Search;
    private static void addPopup(Component component, final JPopupMenu popup) {
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }
            private void showMenu(MouseEvent e) {
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Search_User.java

```
package JAVA_VIDEOS_TUTORIALS;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Search_User {

    private List<String> infoUser;
    private String serachValue;


    public Search_User(String SerachValue)
    {
        this.infoUser = Arrays.asList("Prénom: ", "Nom: ");
        this.serachValue = SerachValue;
    }


    public List<String> getInfoUser() {
        return infoUser;
    }


    public void setInfoUser(List<String> infoUser) {
        this.infoUser = infoUser;
    }


    public String getSerachValue() {
        return serachValue;
    }


    public void setSerachValue(String serachValue) {
        this.serachValue = serachValue;
    }


}
```

User.java

```
package JAVA_VIDEOS_TUTORIALS;

public class User {

    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String name;


    public User(String Id,String Firstname,String Lastname,String Name)
    {
        this.id = Id;
        this.firstname = Firstname;
        this.lastname = Lastname;
        this.name = Name;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstname()
    {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname()
    {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

CustomListRenderer.java

```
package JAVA_VIDEOS_TUTORIALS;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/**
 * @author Mikle Garin
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18589264/909085
 */

public class CustomListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final ImageIcon crossIcon = new ImageIcon ("src/cross.png");

    /**
     * Actual renderer.
     */
    private CustomLabel renderer;

    /**
     * Custom renderer constructor.
     * We will use it to create actual renderer component instance.
     * We will also add a custom mouse listener to process close button.
     *
     * @param list our JList instance
     */
    public CustomListRenderer(final JList<CustomData>list, ArrayList<CustomData> listArrayList)
    {
        super();
        renderer = new CustomLabel();

        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if ( SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
                {
                    int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                    if (index != -1 && list.isSelectedIndex(index))
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = list.getCellBounds(index, index);
                        Point pointWithinCell = new Point (e.getX() - rect.x, e.getY() - rect.y);
                        Rectangle crossRect = new Rectangle(rect.width-rect.width+5,
                                rect.height/2-12/2,12, 12);
                        if (crossRect.contains(pointWithinCell))
                        {
                            DefaultListModel<CustomData> model = (DefaultListModel<CustomData>)list.getModel();
                            model.remove(index);
                            listArrayList.remove(index);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    /**
     * Returns custom renderer for each cell of the list.vcbc
     *
     * @param list         list to process
     * @param value        cell value (CustomData object in our case)
     * @param index        cell index
     * @param isSelected   whether cell is selected or not
     * @param cellHasFocus whether cell has focus or not
     * @return custom renderer for each cell of the list
     */
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent (JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        renderer.setSelected(isSelected);
        renderer.setData((CustomData)value);
        renderer.setToolTipText(renderer.getText());
        return renderer;
    }

    /**
     * Label that has some custom decorations.
     */
    private static class CustomLabel extends JLabel
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private boolean selected;

        public CustomLabel()
        {
            super();
            setOpaque(false);
            setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 30, 0, 0));

        }



        private void setSelected(boolean selected)
        {
            this.selected = selected;
            setForeground(selected ? Color.BLACK : Color.BLACK);
        }

        private void setData(CustomData data)
        {
            setText(data.getName());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint (RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


            g2d.drawImage(crossIcon.getImage(), 0,
                     0, null);

            if (selected)
            {
                g2d.drawImage(crossIcon.getImage(), 0,
                       0, null);
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            final Dimension ps = super.getPreferredSize();
            ps.height = 36;
            ps.width = 115;
            return ps;
        }
    }
}
```

CustomData.java

```
package JAVA_VIDEOS_TUTORIALS;

/**
 * Custom data for our list.
 */
public class CustomData{

    private String name;

    public CustomData(String name)
    {
        super ();
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: How to create a generic class?
Here, I created a "Search_User" class to search for a user by their last name or first name. But I would like to make the generic class so that I can use this code for other searches like for example a product by its name its reference ... And besides, I would like to make parametrizable the elements to search because if tomorrow I want to be able to search a user by his date of birth in addition to his name or first name, I must directly change the java code.